# Group by returns wrong result

Tags: sql-server

I have that query:

```
select e.UserId as UserId, COUNT(*) as [Registrations] from dbo.EventLog as e 
where e.EventTypeId = 3 and e.Value is not null
group by UserId
```

and example data returned by it is:

```
UserId Registrations

1   37

3   1

10  2

12  69

13  22

14  5
```

But I want to select timestamp as well. for that I'm adding `e.[TimeStamp]` in select and it says:

> Column 'dbo.EventLog.TimeStamp' is invalid in the select list because
>   it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

If I'll add `e.[TimeStamp]` in group by result is:

```
UserId Registrations TimesTamp

1   1   2013-01-09 13:29:19.143

25  1   2013-01-09 13:52:37.687

27  1   2013-01-09 15:00:03.147

27  1   2013-01-09 16:12:01.000

27  1   2013-01-10 16:00:53.757

34  1   2013-01-10 17:13:52.000
```

mention that registrations with `id` 1 are in whole row instead of for example 37, 2 etc.

Comment: MySQL and/or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved...

Comment: @TJ- yes and problem is that i need to group it by UserId not using TS

Comment: @jarlh suggestion things.. its ms sql

Comment: So, what's the expected result if a userid has several timestamps? Do you want them all, or just one of them (which one)?

Comment: @George, so if you don't want to group by using TS then there would be multiple TS associated with the single `Id`, in that case which TS you want to include in your end result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A timestamp will probably be different for each row, so which timestamp do you actually mean from the set that shares a UserId?

What you could do is find the first timestamp:

```
select 
   e.UserId as UserId, 
   COUNT(*) as [Registrations],
   Min(e.Timestamp) as [First Timestamp]
from dbo.EventLog as e 
where e.EventTypeId = 3 and e.Value is not null
group by UserId
```

or the last one, using max()

Answer (score 1):

Following is the reasons. Why you get such result.

You are grouping by user Id as well as Timestamp

- There can be multiple userId with your condition(**e.EventTypeId = 3 and e.Value    is not null**) agreed but if you group by timestamp as well
  there is only one user which satisfies that condition and has a timestamp
- If you can put average(timestamp) or min or max in select if you want to have all the registrations.

Good luck

Comment: You should post some example code ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Include what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck. See more info at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect the timestamp column to contain for the grouping representing the 37 registrations of user 1? Since there are also 37 timestamp values, you need an aggregate function for this to be meaningful. E.g. if you want the timestamp of the latest registration for each user, use the MAX function.